# What is the solution to 'ResolvePackageNotFound' error when creating a Conda environment using a .yml file?

Tags: anaconda, conda, environment, conda-build

I am trying to create an environment using this https://github.com/mbareera/MuSA/blob/master/MuSA.yml file but I am getting error below. I am using conda 22.11.1 version. Can anyone help how I can create environment using this yaml file?

```
ResolvePackageNotFound:

cftime==1.6.2=py39h7deecbd_0
mkl_fft==1.3.1=py39hd3c417c_0
libevent==2.1.12=h8f2d780_0
libcurl==7.88.1=h91b91d3_0
packaging==23.0=py39h06a4308_0
ca-certificates==2023.01.10=h06a4308_0
dill==0.3.6=py39h06a4308_0
libthrift==0.15.0=hcc01f38_0
libssh2==1.10.0=h8f2d780_0
zstd==1.5.2=ha4553b6_0
pyqt==5.15.7=py39h6a678d5_1
lz4-c==1.9.4=h6a678d5_0
qt-main==5.15.2=h327a75a_7
python==3.9.16=h7a1cb2a_2
aws-c-event-stream==0.1.6=h2531618_5
aws-c-common==0.4.57=he6710b0_1
cffi==1.15.1=py39h5eee18b_3
mkl==2021.4.0=h06a4308_640
libxcb==1.15=h7f8727e_0
numba==0.56.4=py39h417a72b_0
lcms2==2.12=h3be6417_0
numpy-base==1.23.5=py39h31eccc5_0
re2==2022.04.01=h295c915_0
libgomp==11.2.0=h1234567_1
netcdf4==1.6.2=py39h89d13dc_0
arrow-cpp==10.0.1=py39h613000e_0
statsmodels==0.13.5=py39h7deecbd_1
gflags==2.2.2=he6710b0_0
bottleneck==1.3.5=py39h7deecbd_0
certifi==2022.12.7=py39h06a4308_0
glog==0.5.0=h2531618_0
ncurses==6.4=h6a678d5_0
pysocks==1.7.1=py39h06a4308_0
libgfortran-ng==11.2.0=h00389a5_1
mkl-service==2.4.0=py39h7f8727e_0
lerc==3.0=h295c915_0
mpi4py==3.1.4=py39hfc96bbd_0
grpc-cpp==1.46.1=h33aed49_1
libnghttp2==1.46.0=hce63b2e_0
hdf4==4.2.13=h3ca952b_2
mkl_random==1.2.2=py39h51133e4_0
tornado==6.2=py39h5eee18b_0
gst-plugins-base==1.14.1=h6a678d5_1
fontconfig==2.14.1=h52c9d5c_1
libbrotlienc==1.0.9=h5eee18b_7
scikit-learn==1.2.1=py39h6a678d5_0
ipython==8.10.0=py39h06a4308_0
llvmlite==0.39.1=py39he621ea3_0
traitlets==5.7.1=py39h06a4308_0
libxml2==2.9.14=h74e7548_0
ld_impl_linux-64==2.38=h1181459_1
freetype==2.12.1=h4a9f257_0
icu==58.2=he6710b0_3
qt-webengine==5.15.9=hd2b0992_4
sqlite==3.41.1=h5eee18b_0
jedi==0.18.1=py39h06a4308_1
pyarrow==10.0.1=py39h992f0b0_0
brotli-bin==1.0.9=h5eee18b_7
pyopenssl==23.0.0=py39h06a4308_0
libwebp-base==1.2.4=h5eee18b_1
libboost==1.73.0=h28710b8_12
dbus==1.13.18=hb2f20db_0
gstreamer==1.14.1=h5eee18b_1
scipy==1.10.0=py39h14f4228_1
aws-sdk-cpp==1.8.185=hce553d0_0
nspr==4.33=h295c915_0
libprotobuf==3.20.3=he621ea3_0
qtwebkit==5.212=h4eab89a_4
patsy==0.5.3=py39h06a4308_0
curl==7.88.1=h5eee18b_0
pillow==9.4.0=py39h6a678d5_0
brotli==1.0.9=h5eee18b_7
libllvm10==10.0.1=hbcb73fb_5
giflib==5.2.1=h5eee18b_3
multiprocess==0.70.14=py39h06a4308_0
urllib3==1.26.14=py39h06a4308_0
joblib==1.1.1=py39h06a4308_0
wheel==0.38.4=py39h06a4308_0
kiwisolver==1.4.4=py39h6a678d5_0
matplotlib-base==3.7.1=py39h417a72b_1
intel-openmp==2021.4.0=h06a4308_3561
prompt-toolkit==3.0.36=py39h06a4308_0
hdf5==1.10.6=h3ffc7dd_1
libpq==12.9=h16c4e8d_3
boost-cpp==1.73.0=h7f8727e_12
xz==5.2.10=h5eee18b_1
zipp==3.11.0=py39h06a4308_0
nss==3.74=h0370c37_0
contourpy==1.0.5=py39hdb19cb5_0
pytz==2022.7=py39h06a4308_0
matplotlib-inline==0.1.6=py39h06a4308_0
libbrotlicommon==1.0.9=h5eee18b_7
zlib==1.2.13=h5eee18b_0
c-ares==1.19.0=h5eee18b_0
jpeg==9e=h5eee18b_1
orc==1.7.4=hb3bc3d3_1
libdeflate==1.17=h5eee18b_0
matplotlib==3.7.1=py39h06a4308_1
tbb==2021.7.0=hdb19cb5_0
libuuid==1.41.5=h5eee18b_0
libzip==1.8.0=h5cef20c_0
glib==2.69.1=he621ea3_2
numexpr==2.8.4=py39he184ba9_0
pcre==8.45=h295c915_0
bzip2==1.0.8=h7b6447c_0
_openmp_mutex==5.1=1_gnu
expat==2.4.9=h6a678d5_0
abseil-cpp==20211102.0=hd4dd3e8_0
libev==4.33=h7f8727e_1
brotlipy==0.7.0=py39h27cfd23_1003
libxslt==1.1.35=h4e12654_0
tk==8.6.12=h1ccaba5_0
cryptography==39.0.1=py39h9ce1e76_0
pyparsing==3.0.9=py39h06a4308_0
libwebp==1.2.4=h11a3e52_1
libbrotlidec==1.0.9=h5eee18b_7
pyqt5-sip==12.11.0=py39h6a678d5_1
openssl==1.1.1t=h7f8727e_0
pip==23.0.1=py39h06a4308_0
libffi==3.4.2=h6a678d5_6
libllvm11==11.1.0=h9e868ea_6
libxkbcommon==1.0.1=hfa300c1_0
setuptools==65.6.3=py39h06a4308_0
numpy==1.23.5=py39h14f4228_0
krb5==1.19.4=h568e23c_0
libnetcdf==4.8.1=h8322cc2_2
libgcc-ng==11.2.0=h1234567_1
utf8proc==2.6.1=h27cfd23_0
libclang==10.0.1=default_hb85057a_2
sip==6.6.2=py39h6a678d5_0
idna==3.4=py39h06a4308_0
requests==2.28.1=py39h06a4308_1
aws-checksums==0.1.9=he6710b0_0
libstdcxx-ng==11.2.0=h1234567_1
snappy==1.1.9=h295c915_0
libpng==1.6.39=h5eee18b_0
pandas==1.5.3=py39h417a72b_0
libedit==3.1.20221030=h5eee18b_0
libgfortran5==11.2.0=h1234567_1
ply==3.11=py39h06a4308_0
libtiff==4.5.0=h6a678d5_2
readline==8.2=h5eee18b_0
```

Conda info

```
     active environment : base
    active env location : /Users/bareeramirza/anaconda3
            shell level : 1
       user config file : /Users/bareeramirza/.condarc
 populated config files : /Users/bareeramirza/.condarc
          conda version : 23.5.0
    conda-build version : 3.25.0
         python version : 3.10.11.final.0
       virtual packages : __archspec=1=arm64
                          __osx=12.5=0
                          __unix=0=0
       base environment : /Users/bareeramirza/anaconda3  (writable)
      conda av data dir : /Users/bareeramirza/anaconda3/etc/conda
  conda av metadata url : None
           channel URLs : https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/osx-arm64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/osx-arm64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
          package cache : /Users/bareeramirza/anaconda3/pkgs
                          /Users/bareeramirza/.conda/pkgs
       envs directories : /Users/bareeramirza/anaconda3/envs
                          /Users/bareeramirza/.conda/envs
               platform : osx-arm64
             user-agent : conda/23.5.0 requests/2.29.0 CPython/3.10.11 Darwin/21.6.0 OSX/12.5
                UID:GID : 501:20
             netrc file : None
           offline mode : False
```

I am using macOS Monterey version 12.5 Chip Apple M1 Pro

I tried to create new environment but failed and getting error above.`your text`

Comment: What is your OS? can you add the output of `conda info`?

Comment: I am using macOS Monterey version 12.5 Chip Apple M1 Pro

     active environment : base
    active env location : /Users/bareeramirza/anaconda3
            shell level : 1
       user config file : /Users/bareeramirza/.condarc
 populated config files : /Users/bareeramirza/.condarc
          conda version : 23.5.0
    conda-build version : 3.25.0
         python version : 3.10.11.final.0
       virtual packages : __archspec=1=arm64
                          __osx=12.5=0
                          __unix=0=0

Comment: base environment : /Users/bareeramirza/anaconda3  (writable)
      conda av data dir : /Users/bareeramirza/anaconda3/etc/conda
  conda av metadata url : None
           channel URLs : https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/osx-arm64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/osx-arm64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
          package cache : /Users/bareeramirza/anaconda3/pkgs
                          /Users/bareeramirza/.conda/pkgs

Comment: envs directories : /Users/bareeramirza/anaconda3/envs
                          /Users/bareeramirza/.conda/envs
               platform : osx-arm64
             user-agent : conda/23.5.0 requests/2.29.0 CPython/3.10.11 Darwin/21.6.0 OSX/12.5
                UID:GID : 501:20
             netrc file : None
           offline mode : False

Sorry had to break down conda info because comment can't take too much

Comment: Thank you for adding the information, but please add these info into your question using the [edit] function. This way you can format them properly

Comment: Thank you, I have edited my query. How to get attention to my post for getting answer?

Comment: Exactly like this. people that have already commented get notified when you comment yourself

Comment: Thank you so much! I solved it anyway. I had to reinstall my conda as my root was broken and install some packages manually.